# Regex's match, dash in the subject string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

```
var subject = "Parametre - Bloc Notes"
var match = Regex.Match(subject, "(?i)(?:blah|para|foo).*?");
// This will work 
//"Para" doesn't match "Param" and it is before the dash

var subject = "Parametre - Bloc Notes"
var match = Regex.Match(subject, "(?i)(?:blah|blo|foo).*?");
// This will not work
// "Blo" match "Bloc" and it is after the dash
```

I think "-", is the main cause of my misunderstand.

Edit:

I'm really sorry, so I want the regex to match Param before the dash, how can I do that?

Edit 2:

I admit my question is really ambiguous, so my goal is to find the Parametre word in any string.

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: What is the actual question??

Comment: @BradM ha, beat you by 5 seconds :)

Comment: You're never checking for any dash, why would you expect anything after it to fail the match?

Comment: YOu want to match whatever word comes before the `-` character?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to match a bit more? Simply `(?i)(blah|bloc|foo)` and `(?i)(blah|para|foo)` will both match that string - what other requirements do you have from the regex? Do you want to capture matches or are you just looking to check if it is a match or not?

Comment: Maybe my whole regex is wrong then I just want the regex to find the Parametre word inside any string like the subject variable string.

Comment: I posted something below - can you confirm if it's answering your actual question?  Still not sure if I understand correctly or not.

Comment: "my goal is to find the Parametre" - can you clarify more?  You specifically want to know if the characters "Parametre" show up anywhere in any string, or are there more strict criteria?

Comment: This question is soo unclear and you clarifications add no clarity

Comment: Yes as I wrote in any string, and anywhere.

Comment: I posted this down below as well, but basically this? `"Parametre - Bloc Notes".Contains("Parametre"); // true`?

Comment: Your question is confusing because the regex examples provided in your question don't seem to have any relevance at all to what it seems you're asking now...

Comment: That's it thank you very much and sorry for this unclarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match whatever word comes before the `-` you can simply do this:

```
/(\w+)\s*\-/
```

The first group will be "Parametre" in your above example.  For example,

```
"Foo - bar baz" // first group will be "Foo"

"Hello - World" // first group will be "Hello"
```

---

Update: I seem to have misunderstood your question.  If the intent is simply to know whether or not the word "Parametre" exists in a string, you can use `String.Contains`:

```
"Parametre - Bloc Notes".Contains("Parametre"); // true
```

Alternatively, if you're concerned with word boundaries (i.e., you *don't* want to match "Parametres"), you can still use regex:

```
/\bParametre\b/
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @jmar777, my bad, I made my question very ambiguous, I edited it a second time.

Comment: It's still rather hard to understand what you're looking for.  If all you want is to know if "Parametre" is present, you can just do `"Parametre - Bloc Notes".Contains("Parametre"); // true`